# AngularJS components communication

Tags: angularjs

I need to create two components (child and father) able to communicate each other.
The template is the following:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <father-component>
    <child-component>
      Text 1
    </child-component>
    <child-component>
      Text 2
    </child-component>
  </father-component>
</body>
```

It's possible to select a child component, one at a time with colored backgroud (the other has to be deselected)

The selected child component has to be identified by the father.

Thank you!!

Comment: Yes it is, and you need to show what you tried

Comment: For the moment I've approached only this: https://jsfiddle.net/0kcubxne/